# OpenOffice SDK: convert document to PDF

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, openoffice.org

I'm trying to build an application to convert documents (word, powerpoint) to PDF using the OpenOffice SDK.

I'm using C++ and all I want the application to do is take an input document filename and and output PDF filename, and do the conversion.

Are there any samples or easy way to get started?  Most of the documentation I see is using Java.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, ideally I need to develop a C++ application to convert xls to pdf. So far I've such program working in C# with OO 3.3. I've also found bits of C++ example for this but they make reference to OO header files which are not provided along the std install of OO or even the OO SDK. any pointer on this appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do this with C#, I share with you hoping it helps:

```
// Connect to a running office and get the service manager
unoidl.com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext m_xContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
var mxMSFactory = (XMultiServiceFactory)m_xContext.getServiceManager();
XComponentLoader desktop = (XComponentLoader)mxMSFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
XComponentLoader xComponentLoader = (unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader)desktop;
PropertyValue[] properties = new PropertyValue[1];
properties[0] = new PropertyValue();
properties[0].Name = "Hidden";
properties[0].Value = new uno.Any(true);

XComponent xComponent = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL("file:///YOUR .ODT PATH", "_blank", 0, properties);
XTextDocument xDocument = (XTextDocument)xComponent;

XStorable xStorable = (XStorable)xDocument;
PropertyValue[] storeProps = new PropertyValue[3];
storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
storeProps[0].Name = "FilterName";
storeProps[0].Value = new uno.Any("writer_pdf_Export");
storeProps[1] = new PropertyValue();
storeProps[1].Name = "Overwrite";
storeProps[1].Value = new uno.Any(true);
storeProps[2] = new PropertyValue();
storeProps[2].Name = "SelectPdfVersion";
storeProps[2].Value = new uno.Any(1);

xStorable.storeToURL("file:///YOUR PDF PATH", storeProps);
xDocument.dispose();
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out this code. Could you put more description? What component did you use, and how yours program flow run?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an example source code here:

http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3801

Answer (score -1):

The right way to start is reading the [Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide).

Good stuff in our business ain't easy.